# MongoDB Aggregation Query $match returns nothing with date range, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I can't get the following MongoDB aggregation query to return a result.  It only returns an empty array.  I believe it's because it's not processing the date range correctly.  However, when I do `PriceHourly.find({  date: { $lt: end, $gt: start }})` the records are returned as expected...

```
    var start       = moment.utc('03-02-2012').startOf('day');
    var end         = moment.utc('03-02-2012').add('days',1).startOf('day');

    PriceHourly.aggregate([
        { $match: { date: { $gt: start, $lt: end } } },
        { $group: { _id: null, avgPrice: { $avg: '$price' } } }

    ], function(err, results){
        console.log(err, results);
    });

// Model
var PriceHourlySchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    full_date: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    day: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    hour: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    }
}, 
{ 
    autoIndex: true 
});
```

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question? Did you remove it? If you are sure your date range is correct then there is probably something wrong with "price". A string possibly? You are not posting sample data here so we cannot see it.

Comment: I refined the question based on the latest clues I've found.  I believe the problem lies with the date formats and $match.

Comment: Well you still **really** should be showing your **data**. Please edit your question to show some.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB Aggregation Framework's $match did not understand the Moment Date objects I submitted.  $match appears to only work with native Javascript date objects.  So, if you'd still like to use Moment.js with $match, simply convert the Moment.js Date Objects to Native Javascript Date Objects using Moment's `toDate()` method, like this:

```
var start       = moment.utc(req.query.start).startOf('year').toDate();
var end         = moment.utc(req.query.start).add('years',1).startOf('year').add('hours',1).toDate();
```